# I want the status bar's notification to be invoked

Tags: android, notifications

how to get notification in status bar at a particular time, i tried this, but every particular time the pendingIntents activity is bein called. I want the status bar's notification to be invoked. please help

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    Notification("abduct: ","kidnap");

}   
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void Notification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "First word", 50000);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, null);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1*60*60 , pendingIntent );  //set repeating every 24 hours

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `PendingIntent` you are providing the `AlarmManager`. By creating it with `PendingIntent.getActivity()` you're actually instructing it to *start your activity* when the specified time elapses.

What you need to do is:

- Create a `BroadcastReceiver` and configure it in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
- Instead of what you're currently doing, supply the `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` to send a broadcast to this receiver (with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`).
- In the receiver's `onReceive()`, build and show the notification.

You can find a clear and concise tutorial [here](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html).